# textview onclicklistener gives me no feedback

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener

I've got a manualy createt TextView array in RelativeLayout. All show perfect except: onclicklistener not work
Code:

```
private RelativeLayout mRLMain;
private TextView [] mTV;
private OnClickListener  mTextOnClickListener;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mRLMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMainGame);
    mTV = new TextView[20];

    mSqueareLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mSquareWidth,mSquareWidth);

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        mTV [i] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        mTV [i].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        mTV [i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTV [i].setX(i+100);
        mTV [i].setId(i);

        mTV [i].setOnClickListener(mTextOnClickListener);

        mRLMain.addView(mTV [i], mSqueareLayout);
    }

    mTextOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { Log.d("XXX","CLICK"); }
    };
}
```

Try with

```
mTV [i].setFocusable(false);
mTV [i].setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
mTV [i].setClickable(true);
mTV [i].setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(false);
```

And nothing:
- no errors
- no log's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise your `clickListener` before stting. So change an order can fix your issue.

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    mTV [i] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    mTV [i].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    mTV [i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mTV [i].setX(i+100);
    mTV [i].setId(i);

    // Set clickListener
    mTV [i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("XXX","CLICK");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position "+ i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });

    mRLMain.addView(mTV [i], mSqueareLayout);
}
```

Comment: Yes..Thank's...worked.. But why i can't use setX and setY - i need to use it in future... Anyway - Thank you....

Comment: You can use setX and setY if you require them, but as per your current requirement they were unnecessary. Force changing coordinate can't change click detection. Use object animator, ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationX", i+100, 0);
anim.start();

Answer (score 0):

If the *ClickListener* will have some complex logic, it is even better to extract it to separate class (inner class, for example).

```
// same top part
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            mTV [i] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            mTV [i].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mTV [i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            mTV [i].setX(i+100);
            mTV [i].setId(i);

            // main change here
            mTV [i].setOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener(i));

            mRLMain.addView(mTV [i], mSqueareLayout);
        }
    }

static class CustomClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int viewId;

    // another option is to pass a reference to a view here
    // private View view;
    // in this case, you should create appropriate constructor

    public CustomClickListener(int viewId) {
        this.viewId = viewId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("XXX","Click on view " + viewId);
        // some logic on this view
    }
}
```